# Formatting sent email from Pony.mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, pony

I made a contact form for my web app using Pony.  I have yet to figure out how to format the email with certain fields from the form.  I would like the email formatted in the way below,

First Name: "user inputted first name"
Last Name: "user inputted last name"

Does anyone have any experience with Pony that has achieved this yet?  I can post code snippets if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im new to Rails, I sometimes forget im using Ruby.  Anyways I just called the value associated with each param key.  So (First Name: #{fname}\nLast Name: #{lname}).